# Scroll to several elements in their own overflowed divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have several components/div's that overflow on the x axis. I'm calling `element.scrollIntoView()` for 1 element in each of these scrolling components `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   console.log(prevProps)
   console.log(prevState)
   let activeAsst = getActiveCall(prevProps.detail)
   if (activeAsst == null) {
     return
   }
   let element = document.getElementById(`airCrew_${activeAsst.rep.id}`)
   if (element.scrollIntoView) {
     console.log("scrolling")
     element.scrollIntoView()  
   }
}
```

This is working for the first of these scrollable components. The rest do not scroll. I can see the `console.log("scrolling")` for each of the scrollable components.

Any idea why? I'm only targeting chrome so don't worry about other browsers.

edit: also tried `element.scrollIntoViewIfNecessary()` with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Bah, my mistake. I was generating the id's of the elements incorrectly and they had the same id. There for the same element was being scrolled to each time. This would have been annoying to debug if I had live data, phew.